# how is ApiOriginFilter.java generated

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-codegen

I have a project which I found `ApiOriginFilter.java` under generated code, is this auto generated by swagger?

And,

There is a method `doFilter` which contains response headers.

Currently, a value is set to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *`, I want to change to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : http://example.org`

As this file is auto generated, which yaml file and where should I add my change so that `http://exampl.org` will appear instead of `*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swagger-codegen generates source files based on mustache templates.
In the folder for the spring templates you can see the following supporting file:
apiOriginFilter.mustache

you can the change Access-Control-Allow-Origin inside of the template file.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/modules/swagger-codegen/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/apiOriginFilter.mustache

There's more details on modifying templates inside the README.md

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/